# Setting up SQL server multiple Names but within the same Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

Can we create different SQL Name (so will not change the previous connection strings) in a single SQL Server with the same content of the Database and log-in credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a CNAME record in DNS

there are a few gotchas though so worth reading through the article

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2663/using-friendly-names-for-sql-servers-via-dns/

if you only need to "rename " the server from a single client there are other alternatives